# How to pass a components? [ laravel, vue ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two components `App.vue` and `ModalComponents` and  pass to `fetchUser function` in **App.vue** to **ModalComponents**.

How can I achieve this?

in **App.vue**

```
<pre>
 <script>
   export default {
     methods: {
        fetchUser() {
           fetch('api/employee').then(res => res.json())
           .then(res => {
               this.emp = res.data;
            })
        }
     }
   }
 </script>
</pre>
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: u want do it reutilizable?

Comment: use $emit method by vue

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo yep, bro

Comment: @codeformoney how, bro?

Comment: if is so, then use [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), [this example](https://css-tricks.com/using-mixins-vue-js/) looks well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Vue mixins feature?
At App.vue

```
<script>
import ModalComponents from '@/ModalComponents'
export default {
  mixins: [ModelComponents],
  mounted(){
    this.fetchUser()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what about in ModalComponents ? dont we add anything in it?
i still cant understant clearly about it..

Answer (score 0):

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ModalComponents :emps="emp">
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        emp: null,
      }
    }
    methods: {
      fetchUser() {
          fetch('api/employee').then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
              this.emp = res.data;
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**ModalComponents**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{emps.name}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'emps'
  ],
}
</script>
```

**Otherway**

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ModalComponents v-on:fetch-user="getUser">
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        emp: null,
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getUser(newEmp) {
        this.emp = newEmp
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

**ModalComponents**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="fetchUser">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    fetchUser() {
        fetch('api/employee').then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.emp = res.data;
        })

        const newEmp = this.emp

        this.$emit('fetch-user', newEmp)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if i want `fetchUser() function` pass to ModalComponents?

Comment: you need to put your `fetchUser()` function to your **ModalComponents** and then $emit the data to your **App.vue**

Comment: i dont know how to implement it? can u tell me a bit more detail?

Comment: @CamBoKiDz i edited my answer try the **Other way**